# How do you match a string with optional encapsulating tags

Tags: regex

I basically need to parse some HTML which is oddly formatted.

It might be wrapped in a anchor tag or it might not.

e.g.

```
<a href="something">capture text</a> ...some other html
```

or just

```
capture text ...some other html
```

How can I construct a pattern than knows to ignore `<a href="something">` and the subsequent `</a>` afterwards? Ideally being able to capture the "capture text" part as a named group. I've tried just doing an either pattern but it complains about the named group being the same, is there a way around this?

[Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/kG5vF1/4) with unit tests that show if the regex can match with and without tags to the same group identifier if possible.

Comment: You should really consider using a tool such as BeautifulSoup which specializes in parsing malformed HTML. Care to post your attempt otherwise?

Comment: @Aaron I could do it via manipulation of the HTML but sadly most of it isn't uniform and IMO the regex route is probably the still

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3982562